# Pattern Matching casting

Tags: scala

I have external service which returns AnyRef I want to cast result to Boolean, or return false if return is not Boolean.

Here is a example:

```
object ExternalService {

  def sendEvent(s: String) : AnyRef = {
    return true   } 
  }

object Caller {

  def isValid(s: String): Boolean = {

    val value = ExternalService.sendEvent("test")
    value match {
      // pattern type is incompatible with expected type found Boolean expected AnyRef
      case b: Boolean => b
      case _ => false
    }   
  } 
}
```

but i got

> Error:(6, 12) the result type of an implicit conversion must be more
>   specific than AnyRef
>       return true; Error:(6, 12) type mismatch;  found   : Boolean(true)  required: AnyRef
>       return true; Error:(17, 15) pattern type is incompatible with expected type;  found   : Boolean  required: Object
>         case b: Boolean => b

How can I cast AnyRef to Boolean in this case or in general?

Comment: Try matching on `java.lang.Boolean` instead - unlike scala's version, that doesn't inherit from `AnyVal` so should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems with your code:

The first is that you're trying to return `true` from a method returning `AnyRef`. However, `scala.Boolean` isn't of that type (it inherits from `AnyVal` instead) and the compiler is not happy to be asked to find an implicit conversion to "any reference type". Either you need to change your method to return `Any`, or you need to make sure to return the "boxed" Boolean reference type - `java.lang.Boolean` - instead.

Same for the match statement - there's no way for a value of type `AnyRef` to be `scala.Boolean`, and you don't have access to a lot of implicit conversion logic in a pattern match statement. Again, if you use `Any` instead of `AnyRef` everything will work.

So the working version of your code:

```
object ExternalService {

  def sendEvent(s: String) : Any = {
    true
  }
}

object Caller {

  def isValid(s: String): Boolean = {

    val value = ExternalService.sendEvent("test")
    value match {
      // pattern type is incompatible with expected type found Boolean expected AnyRef
      case b : Boolean => b
      case _ => false
    }
  }
}
```

or, if you really need the return type of `sendEvent` to be `AnyRef`:

```
object ExternalService {

  def sendEvent(s: String) : AnyRef = {
    Boolean.box(true)
  }
}

object Caller {

  def isValid(s: String): Boolean = {

    val value = ExternalService.sendEvent("test")
    value match {
      // pattern type is incompatible with expected type found Boolean expected AnyRef
      case b : java.lang.Boolean => b
      case _ => false
    }
  }
}
```

(The compiler can manage the conversion from `java.lang.Boolean` to `scala.Boolean` in the output of the match statement, so you don't need to explicitly unbox there.)

Comment: Another option for the second case would be `(ExternalService.sendEvent("test"): Any) match ...`

Comment: true, or `val value = ExternalService.sendEvent("test").asInstanceOf[Any]`.

Comment: Always prefer type ascription to `asInstanceOf` where possible. The good alternative would be `val value: Any = ExternalService.sendEvent("test")`.